SQLModel with FastAPI: Editable computed field
I have the following SQLModel in my FastAPI app:
class MyModel(SQLModel):
     a: str

I want to add another field b that will have a default value based on a value provided in model creation. This b field must be also editable in model creation.
I tried using @computed_field but it only allows to auto-generate the value and not override it in model creation.
The b field should be something like:
b: str = Field(default="option1" if len(a) > 5 else "option2")
Model creation should be:
my_model = MyModel(a="abcde") 
to get:
MyModel(a="abcde", b="option2")

or:
my_model = MyModel(a="some_value", b="option3") 
to get:
 MyModel(a="some_value", b="option3")

How can I create an editable computed filed in SQLModel?

You can use the model_validator with mode='before' to inspect the various fields of your model before it's created and modify accordingly.
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str

    @model_validator(mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def check_b(cls, data: Any) -> Any:
        if data.get('b'):
            return data
        data['b'] = "option1" if len(data.get('a')) > 5 else "option2"
        return data

print(Foo(a="abcde").model_dump())
#{'a': 'abcde', 'b': 'option2'}
print(Foo(a="abcdef").model_dump())
#{'a': 'abcdef', 'b': 'option1'}
print(Foo(a="some_value", b="option3").model_dump())
#{'a': 'some_value', 'b': 'option3'}

